# Is it possible to use dispenseXXX error codes with Cook trait?

Tags: google-smart-home

Could you please clarify if it's possible to use the following error codes with Cook trait:

- dispenseAmountRemainingExceeded: <device(s)> doesn't have enough <dispense_item> to do that;
- dispenseFractionalAmountNotSupported: <device(s)> can't dispense fractions of <dispense_item>;
- dispenseFractionalUnitNotSupported: <device(s)> doesn't support fractions of that unit for <dispense_item>;
- dispenseUnitNotSupported: <device(s)> doesn't support that unit for <dispense_item> ?

If possible, what value will be used instead of <dispense_item> in the error message? What needs to be done for this?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, the platform [error codes](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/reference/errors-exceptions) are not trait-specific and you can report whichever error suits your use case. There is an exception to this, however, for errors respond with a parameter from the request (like the `dispense_item` in your example). These errors will not return the proper response if they are returned from a different `EXECUTE` command (we are working in clarifying this in our documentation).

While this is currently not supported, it's a reasonable request so you could consider filing a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=655104&template=1284148). In the short term, it might also suit your use case to implement the [Dispense](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/dispense) trait if you wish to support these conditions.